# Excluding weekends and holidays and display prior Friday

Tags: excel-formula

I need to exclude weekends and holidays from some formulas I use to add/minus days from the date of expiration. I need to exclude weekends and holidays and if the date falls on a weekend or holiday I need it to display the date for the Friday before.

I found the formula below on your site and works perfectly to exclude the weekend and show it as the previous Friday, however, I also need it to exclude a list of holidays.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=1,A2-2,IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,A2-1,A2))
```

I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: can you link the question from where you got that formula.  I would like to add an updated answer using WORKDAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Workday which allows the use of a range of cells that contains the holiday dates:

```
=IF(WORKDAY(A2-1,1,YourRangeofHolidays)=A2,A2,WORKDAY(A2+1,-1,YourRangeofHolidays))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. The first formula I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219834/excel-if-date-falls-on-weekend-default-to-previous-friday/68728367#68728367

Comment: If it worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Hey so I've been doing some more testing and found a slight issue. When I use this formula "=IF(WORKDAY(I5-1,1,Holidays)=I5,I5,WORKDAY(I5+1,-1,Holidays))" and I5 is 9/6/2021 which is a holiday, it returns the date of 9/3 which is not the expected result of 9/4. 

If it's a holiday i would expect it to be the day before the holiday.

Comment: hahaha... just kidding.... sorry was looking at aug calendar. my bad, thank you :)